# How to use jupyter-widgets in Jupyterq/embedpy?

Tags: jupyter, kdb

Ho can I create widgets in jupyterq?

I tried to create them in python but that won't render them

```
/%python
import ipywidgets as widgets
wx=widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['1', '2', '3'],
    value='2',
    description='Number:',
    disabled=False,)
wx
```

If I create the object and then call it in q it only shows it as foreign object, but again wouldn't render it

```
.p.get`wx
{[f;x]embedPy[f;x]}[foreign]enlist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display this if you run the code as follows

```
/%python
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
wx=widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['1', '2', '3'],
    value='2',
    description='Number:',
    disabled=False,)
display(wx)
```

However as [here](https://github.com/KxSystems/jupyterq/issues/12) widgets are a bit experimental at the moment. We're working to fix this but a set timeline on when this would be integrated is not known at present.